# Dependence of complexity of graph algorithms on weight of edges?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

This might be a silly question, but why doesn't the complexity depend on weight of the edges present in the graph?

Comment: Another example of where complexities depend on edge weights is with algorithms for special cases of computationally difficult graph problems (ie NP-hard/NP-complete). Though those are generally only practical if some metric such as max edge weight or total edge weight is sufficiently small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different graph algorithms and in some cases the complexities *do* depend on the edge weights. For example, the [Ford-Fulkerson max-flow algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) has runtime O(mF), where F is the maximum possible flow, which depends on the maximum capacity of the edges. Other algorithms like Dijkstra's algorithm have runtimes that are independent of the edge lengths because it's assumed in the computational model that operations on those weights always take time O(1).

Generally speaking, algorithms with runtimes that depend on the weights/capacities/lengths of the edges in the graph gain their dependency by iterating a number of times based on the capacities/weights/lengths of those edges. If the algorithm only does numeric computations on the weights etc., there typically isn't a dependency because arithmetic operations typically are only considered to take time O(1) unless there's a reason to believe otherwise.

Hope this helps!